# Angular 6 : decimal pipe for comma separation not working

Tags: angular, angular6

i have tried

```
{{111234 | number:'':'en-gb'}}
```

and

```
{{111234 | number:'':'en-in'}}
```

both are showing up as `111,234`.

I want it to look like `1,11,234`

What change i am supposed to make ???

Comment: why should it look like `1,11,234`? Is this ever a valid number?

Comment: In india, yes. We pronounce it as One Lakh Eleven Thousand Two hundred and thirty four.

Comment: did you add angular locale file?

Comment: I don't think @jameelM. Plz guide where and how to add

Comment: https://angular.io/guide/i18n#setting-up-the-locale-of-your-app

Comment: are you using AngularCLI?

Comment: adding to @JameelM: comment, When locale not supplied, uses the value of LOCALE_ID, which is en-US by default. For more, please read: https://angular.io/api/common/DecimalPipe

Comment: You can go through this documentation for setting up the internalization https://angular.io/guide/i18n

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set your [project's locale](https://angular.io/guide/i18n#setting-up-the-locale-of-your-app) as suggested on the comments. that is the preferred way.

yet another way to do it would be with the native `.toLocaleString()` function.

**Component**

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
    wind;

    ngOnInit() {
      this.wind = window;
    }
}
```

**HTML**

```
<h1>{{wind.Number("111234").toLocaleString('en-IN')}}</h1>
```

Haven't tested but it should work